# Ajax Delete in Laravel

Tags: html, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

how to delete data in a table without refreshing the page here is my href button

this two buttons are delete one is to archive and one is to force delete 
the problem is they are refreshing when clicked.

```
  <td><a href="/admin/clients/archTrash/{{ $client->id }}" class="btn btn-info">Active</a></td>


 <td><a href="/admin/clients/archTrashPermanent/{{ $client->id }}" class="fa fa-trash btn btn-danger"></a></td>
```

my controller

```
    $client = new Client;
    $client->client_code = $request->input('client_code');
    $client->client_name = $request->input('client_name');

   $client->save();
```

**EDITED**

Routes

```
 Route::get('/admin/clients/archTrash/{id}', 'Admin\ClientsController@archTrash');

Route::get('/admin/clients/archTrashPermanent/{id}', 'Admin\ClientsController@archTrashPermanent');
```

Comment: add your routes / web.php file

Comment: @SaurabhMistry edited the code sir ! look above the code below i edited it can you help me with it? thanks

Comment: you have put a link tag , so it will redirect your page , instead use button

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `Route::get` use `Route::delete`.

In addition to that change the type: 'Put' to type: 'DELETE' in the ajax call.

```
$Users = UserModel::find($id);
$Users->delete($id);
```

can be written as:

```
UserModel::find($id)->delete();
```

For more help, you may visit those [Link1](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/delete-record-using-ajax-call-with-laravel) [Link2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/how-to-do-an-ajax-delete)

Comment: will that help me to not refresh the page?

Comment: Of course, that will help you and a little advice please learn  [How Ajax work](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-ajax-works)

Comment: im new in laravel cant really get that much sorry :( pls

Comment: Maybe link 1 and link 2 will help you much

Comment: where's the ajax ? @Antu

Comment: what you mean by where's the ajax? cannot get it. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Youve said this `In addition to that change the type: 'Put' to type: 'DELETE' in the ajax call.`  . I still dont have ajax how should i do it?

Comment: Oh dear that was an idea about how to do I provide you laravel two links please follow that link then you will better understand how to do what and one more thing there is no magic in programming you must have to learn every part otherwise you will not do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

in your blade template do like this :

```
 <td><button type="button" data-client_id="{{ $client->id }}" class="btn-archive btn btn-info">Active</button></td>

<td><button type="button" data-client_id="{{ $client->id }}" class="btn-delete fa fa-trash btn btn-danger"></button></td>
```

now add below ajax script :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click','.btn-archive',function(){
   var clientID=$(this).attr('data-client_id');
   var url='/admin/clients/archTrash/'+clientID;
   callAjax(url);
});

$(document).on('click','.btn-delete',function(){
   var clientID=$(this).attr('data-client_id');
   var url='/admin/clients/archTrashPermanent/'+clientID;
   callAjax(url);
});

function callAjax(url){
   $.ajax({
       url:url,
       dataType:'json',
       type:'GET',
       success:function(response){
          console.log(response);
       },
       error:function(err){
         console.log(err);
       }
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: when I click the button nothing happens why is it not working sir: (

Comment: I put **<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  ** but still not working

Comment: It is realy getting close but still i need to refresh before it will delete why is that :(

Comment: still not working sir.. when i click nothing happens and if i refresh the data will remove automatically why is that?

Comment: ill wait more for you answer b4 i mark ur answer as answered thank. Ill wait si thank you

Comment: I think it is really closed. It is working now. Tho it needs to refresh before the data will be remove pls help thanks

Comment: Sir, @Saurabh Mistry , can you finish the code please? please update it without refreshing. the problem with ur code is i need to refresh before the row of the table will remove

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to make two ajax call's to controller using front side. Let's say you are using jquery then:

```
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" url="/admin/clients/archTrash/{{ $client->id }}" onClick="deleteAjax(this);" class="btn btn-info">Active</a></td>
```

Then in jquery function deleteAjax make a call by getting attribute:

```
function deleteAjax (elm) {
        var element = $(elm);
        ajax({
              url: element.attr('url'),
              type: 'GET',
              success: function(data){
                 console.log(data)
              }
          });
   }
```

Now in controller simply put deleted_at entry in record to delete temporary purpose i.e. :

```
      UserModel::where('id', $id)->first()->delete();  //if softdelete is enabled
```

And then on response simply remove that element.

Same process for force delete.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes in your example it is Client.